# How can I ensure a Textarea field grows in both height and width?

Tags: html, css, textarea, border-box

I'm a beginner at web development and I'm working on a website and have a Textarea field that I want to use to allow users to write longer text. I've applied CSS styles to make the field grow in height as the user enters more text, and that's working perfectly.
However, I'm having trouble ensuring that the container grows also in width when the user drags the textarea to the right. The container that holds the Textarea field doesn't automatically adjust its width to accommodate the text, and the Textarea field overflows beyond the container. [see picture][image: pic]

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 300px auto 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.container>* {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.postForm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="postForm">
    <form>
      <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Tell us about your post..."></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I ensure that the container also grows in width when the Textarea field is resized?

I thought with box-sizing: border-box; it will work but unfortunately it doesn't work. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I would submit to you to add a max-width to the textarea element. That way, the textarea does resize past the parent container, but if you want the user to resize as much, you can place an overflow on the parent container of the textarea to accommodate the length. I made modifications to the existing code to show both scenarios.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.container>* {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

textarea{
 max-width:100%;
}

.overflow { overflow:scroll }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="postForm">
    <form>
      <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Tell us about your post..."></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overflow">
  <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Tell us about your post..."></textarea>
</div>
```